# Fail to run git command in specific directory in global post-commit hook

Tags: git, git-submodules, post-commit, post-commit-hook

I am trying to use a submodule with a global post-commit hook but find an issue.

### Description

Consider we have two git directories A and B. A is the super-project of B.

Here's my script in the global post-commit hook.

```bash
#!/bin/sh 
git -C path/to/A remote show origin
```

### Expected behavior

It supposes to show the remote information about A after committing in B.

### Actual behavior

It shows remote information about B after I committed in B.

### Questions

- Did I do anything wrong to cause the unexpected result?
- If not, Why did this happen? (maybe caused by the limitation of post-commit hooks? [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_commit))
- How do I get the expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git hooks run *because of* some Git command, and like any internal Git command, they're run with an *environment setup* that specifies which particular repository is to be used.  This means that in general you're not supposed to do operations on *some other repository*.

If you know precisely what you're doing, though, you can *unset* the various Git environment variables that control the specific repository, index, working tree, and/or other Git settings that Git is using.  Note that you may need to do this for potentially many (and ever-more in the future) Git variables, so it's not wise to do this without a really good reason.

The one variable in particular that you must *always* unset here is `GIT_DIR`.  That is:

```
git -C <path> ...
```

doesn't work because `GIT_DIR` is set, but:

```
unset GIT_DIR
git -C <path> ...
```

will remove the `GIT_DIR` setting and the subsequent `git -C` operation will work.  Note that by unsetting `GIT_DIR` here, you make it difficult to operate on the post-commit's repository, so you might in some cases want to do this in a sub-shell.